# How to delete records from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables:

```
Files (primary key = FileID)
Accounts (primary key = AccountID)
AccFiles (2 fields: FileID and AccountID)
```

The `AccFiles` table links the primary keys of the `Files` table to the `Accounts` table.

In my scenario, if there is an Account record there will also be 1 corresponding File in the Files table and a reference to both in the `AccFiles` table. I guess this is a 1 to 1 relationship. Unfortunately due to a bug some files got deleted but their Account and the record in the AccFiles table didn’t. I need to write a SQL script that will delete records from the `Accounts` table and `AccFiles` table where there is no longer a corresponding File (as referenced by the `Accfiles FileID`).

I’m using SQL Server and have no idea how to go about doing this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete all records from `AccFiles` whose `FileId` field does not exist in the `File` table then delete all records from `Accounts` whose `AccountId` field does not exist in the `AccFiles` table:

```
DELETE AccFiles
WHERE FileID
NOT IN
(
  SELECT FileID
  FROM Files
);

DELETE Accounts
WHERE AccountId
NOT IN
(
  SELECT AccountId
  FROM AccFiles
);
```